# canceling get-credentials in loop

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am working on developing PowerShell script to automate a task on a remote server by using Invoke-Command with WinRM.

The script will take the server IP, test WinRM and "Get-Credential" cmdlet to establish session and use Invoke-Command to run another script on remote server. I have made significant progress of what I want to achieve, however, I am having trouble on how to setup the code so that when I press the "Cancel" or "X" button on Get-Credential prompt it should abort the script and return to the regular PowerShell command line prompt.

Below is what I have so far, I have erased the comments and description of the code to keep the number of words less in here.

```
function SS
{

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $BInput = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do you want to proceed?', 'Confirmation',[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo)
         switch ($BInput)
         { 
            "Yes" {             
                    while ($true)
                        {
                            $server=Read-Host "Enter Server IP Address"  
                            set-item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "$server" -Force
                                if(Test-WSMan -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
                                    {
                                        Write-Host "$server is accessible, enter credentials to connect"
                                        
                                            while ($true)
                                                {
                                                    $creden=Get-Credential -Message "Please enter the server credentials that you want to connect"
                                                    $serversession = New-Pssession -ComputerName $server -Credential $creden -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                                                    if(-not($serversession))
                                                       {
                                                        write-warning "Credentials are not valild, please try again"                                                            
                                                       }
                                                    else
                                                       {
                                                        write-host "$server is connected, starting the workflow ......"                                                            
                                                        Invoke-Command -Session $serversession -FilePath "C:\Temp\XXX.ps1"                                                            
                                                       }                                                                         
                                                }
                                            Break
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        write-host "Windows Remote Management (WinRM) protocol is not running, please check service and confirm."
                                    }
                        }
                    
                    Get-Pssession | Remove-PSSession
                    
                  }
                                     
            "No"  {  

                    Break
                  }
        }     
      
 }
```

I understand I have to apply the changes / logic after this line

```
$creden=Get-Credential -Message "Please enter the server credentials that you want to connect"
```

But can't seem to find it yet. I looked online and have taken different approaches but no success so far. I would like to have opinions or recommendations on how to tackle this, appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Nice script!  A few things you might want to consider though.  Is having a pop-up window asking if the user wants to to continue really necessary?  I might instead just go straight to asking to enter a server IP and if the response to that is empty or invalid IP then I might exit the script then.  Additionally users can always press Ctrl-C to quit the script.  If sticking with asking whether to continue or not maybe replace the pop-up with just a `$response  = Read-Host "Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/N)"` and check if a 'Y' or 'N' was returned. If not loop and ask again or assume N.

Comment: Good work overall, but you have a lot of error handling issues that you are not addressing and your function naming should follow documented standards. I'll post back later a refactor of what you posted to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

What i'm seeing is that you may be thinking too much into it. A simple `if` statement should do the trick, try:

```
$creden=Get-Credential -Message "Please enter the server credentials that you want to connect"
    if(!$creden){break}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.
Try this refactor of your use case.

***Point of note: Note fully tested since I do not have an environment at this time to test.***

```
Function Start-WorkFlow
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Execute a workflow
    .DESCRIPTION
        Sets up a WinRM session to a remote host to execute the defined workflow
    .EXAMPLE
        Start-WorkFlow
    .EXAMPLE
        swf
    .INPUTS
        Remote host IPAddress
        Remove host credentials
    .OUTPUTS
        Resutls of teh workflow
    .NOTES
        V 0.0.1 - Prototype script. Clean-Up before production use
    .COMPONENT
        Stand-alone script
    .ROLE
        Administrative actions
    .FUNCTIONALITY
        Implemetned error logic for each code block
        Restrict the user input to only be a proper IPAddress
        Validate TCPIP state 
        Validate WSman state
        Establish a new session
        Process workflow
        Exit session
    #>

    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('swf')]
    Param
    (

    )

    
    If ((Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to proceed: [Yes/No]') -eq 'No' )
    {Break}
    Else
    {
        Do {$RemoteServerIPAddress = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server IP Address')}
        Until ($RemoteServerIPAddress -match "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")

        Get-ChildItem -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts'

        Try
        {
            (Test-Connection -ComputerName $RemoteServerIPAddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop).IPV4Address
            # Set-Item -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts' -Value $RemoteServerIPAddress -Force

            Get-ChildItem -Path 'WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts'

            Try 
            {
                Test-WSMan -ComputerName $RemoteServerIPAddress -ErrorAction Stop
                "$RemoteServerIPAddress is accessible, enter credentials to connect"
                Do 
                {
                    $Creds        = $null
                    $CredMesssage = 'Please enter the remote server credentials that you want to connect.' 
                    $CredMesssage = "$CredMesssage If credentials are not valid, you will be prompted to re-enter them."
                    $Creds        = Get-Credential -Message $CredMesssage

                    if(-Not $creds)
                    {
                        Write-Warning -Message 'Credential request cancelled.'
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
                        Exit
                    }
                    
                    $NewPSSessionSplat = @{
                        ComputerName = $RemoteServerIPAddress
                        Credential   = $Creds 
                        Name         = 'RemoteSessionName'
                        ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
                    }
                    New-PSSession $NewPSSessionSplat
                }
                Until (Get-PSSession -Name 'RemoteSessionName')

                "$RemoteServerIPAddress is connected, starting the workflow ......"
                Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteServerSession -FilePath 'C:\Temp\XXX.ps1'
            }
            Catch 
            {
                Write-Warning -Message 'Session connection results:'
                $PSitem.Exception.Message
            }
            Finally
            {
                Get-PSSession | 
                Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue        
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "
            The remote server $RemoteServerIPAddress is not available
            Exiting the session."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            Exit
        }
    }
}


Start-WorkFlow
```